# Как с помощью функции create_user() зарегистрировать пользователя с подтверждением пароля

Tags: orm, kohana, php

Как с помощью функции create_user() зарегистрировать пользователя с подтверждением пароля - куда тут нужно передать содержимое поля формы 'password_confirm':

```
 ORM::factory('user')
        ->create_user($_POST, array('username', 'email','password','confirm' ))                                                  
->add('roles', ORM::factory('role', array('name' => 'login')));
```

и вообще - как этой функцией пользоваться - может ее нужно переопределить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контроллер

```
public function action_register()

{
    if (!empty($_POST)){

        $data = Arr::extract($_POST, array('username', 'password', 'password_confirm', 'email'));

        if(Captcha::valid($_POST['captcha']) == true)
        {
            $validation = Validation::factory($_POST);
            $validation -> rule('email', 'email');
            if($validation->check())
            {
                $users = ORM::factory('user');

                try 
                {
                    $users->create_user($_POST, array(
                        'username',
                        'password',
                        'email', 
                    ));

                    $role = ORM::factory('role')->where('name', '=', 'login')->find();
                    $users->add('roles', $role);

                    $this->action_login();
                    $this->request->redirect(URL::site('/auth/successfully'));
                }
                catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e) 
                {
                    $errors = $e->errors('auth');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $errors = $validation->errors('validation');
            }

        }  
        else
        {
            $errors = array(Kohana::message('captcha/err', 'error_1'));
        }
    }

    $captcha = Captcha::instance('default');

    $content = View::factory('index/auth/v_auth_register')
            ->bind('captcha', $captcha)
            ->bind('errors', $errors)
            ->bind('data', $data);

    // Выводим в шаблон
    $this->template->page_title = 'Регистрация';
    $this->template->block_center = array($content);
}
```

Модель

<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

```
class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User {

public function labels()
{
    return array(
        'username' => 'Логин',
        'email' => 'E-mail',
        'password' => 'Пароль',
        'password_confirm' => 'Повторить пароль',
    );
}

public function rules()
{
return array(
        'username' => array(
    array('not_empty'),
    array('min_length', array(':value', 4)),
    array('max_length', array(':value', 32)),
            array(array($this, 'unique'), array('username', ':value')),
            ),
        'password' => array(
    array('not_empty'),
            ),
        'email' => array(
    array('not_empty'),
    array('min_length', array(':value', 6)),
    array('max_length', array(':value', 127)),
    array('email'),
            array(array($this, 'unique'), array('email', ':value')),
            ),
        );
}
```

}

Comment: Валидация email не через модуль Auth. Там какой то баг в модуле. Поэтому использую стандартную валидацию